# Rails associations multiple string foreign key

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I can't seem to figure out how to match more than one string column for the foreign key. I have two models. Shop and Neighborhood. Both have City and State column.

How can I set up an association with multiple foreign key string? Right now a neighborhood of Vancouver, BC will show shops for Vancouver, BC and Vancouver, WA.

```
Shop
- ID
- City (String)
- State (string)
- Country (string)

belongs_to :neighborhood, foreign_key: :city, primary_key: :city

Neighborhood
- ID
- City (String)
- State (String)
- Country (String)

has_many :shops, foreign_key: :city, primary_key: :city
```

Comment: why don't you just add a neighborhood_id to the shops-Table and drop city, state and country-columns there?

Comment: I will have shops from around the world, but I will only have a few cities in the neighborhood table.

Comment: Will keeping the city, state, country in a different table like `Areas` and having an `area_id` in both the table work for you? Not sure about the solution just trying to help.

Comment: OK then but i would still suggest to add a neighbourhood_id to the shop-table. As far as I know there is no way to add a multi-string-key-relationship in rails and implementing one by hand is likely having you fight against the framework. Or implement something like @Deep suggested if you want to reduce duplicate data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Took a break and came up with a simple solution.

Shop model:

```
belongs_to :neighborhood, foreign_key: :city, primary_key: :city
```

with

```
def neighborhood
  Neighborhood.find_by_city_and_state(city, state)
end
```

Neighborhood model:

```
has_many :shops, foreign_key: :city, primary_key: :city
```

with

```
def shops
  Shop.where(city: city, state: state)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern could be improved.

You're referencing a "[`foreign_key`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)" with a *string*... it should be an `integer`. If you refactor your pattern, the issue will go away completely...

```
#app/models/shop.rb
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
   # id | city_id | ...
   belongs_to :city
end

#app/models/city.rb
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :shops
   belongs_to :state #-> can be removed
end

#app/models/state.rb
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :country #-> can be removed
end
```

By its nature, a `foreign_key` has to identify the `primary_key` (`unique_key`) of the associative table:

> In context of relational databases, a foreign key is a field (or collection of fields) in one table that **uniquely** identifies a row of another table

This means that if you're referencing a *city*, it should not matter if the "name" of the city is the same... if the other table contains appropriate data (IE a `City` is uniquely located within a `State` etc).

--

I would recommend refactoring your models so that `Shop belongs_to City`. You'd then be able to associate each `City` with respective `states` etc.

Instead of including a `State` & `Country` model, you could use the [`countries`](https://github.com/hexorx/countries) gem, which includes references to the various countries in the world, and their states.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.